# How to retrieve object property values with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, ecmascript-6

In the following code, `users` is an object that I need to convert into an array with just the property values:

```
users = [
  { mobile: '88005895##' },
  { mobile: '78408584##' },
  { mobile: '88008335##' }
];
```

**Desired Output:**

```
[88005895##,78408584##,88008335##];
```

---

The following `jQuery` code is working but I don't know how to achieve the same thing with pure JavaScript:

```
var objNumber = $.map(users, function(value, index) {
  return [value];
});
console.log(objNumber);
```

**What I have tried so far:**

```
var objNumber = Object.keys(users).map(function (key) { return users[key]; });
```

Comment: users.map( value => [value])

Comment: have you tried googling JS equiv $.map etc.?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map

Comment: Voting to re-open this question since OP has provided an example of what he has tried so far.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) method along with the *ES6* [fat arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) expression to retrieve the values in one line like this:

```
users.map(x => x.mobile);
```

---

Check the **Code Snippet** below for a practical example of the *ES6 approach* above:

```js
var users = [{mobile:'88005895##'},{mobile:'78408584##'},{mobile:'88008335##'}];
       
var mob = users.map(x => x.mobile);

console.log(mob);
```

---

Or if you prefer an *ES5 approach* without the *fat arrow function*, you can map the array like this:

```
users.map(function(x) {
  return x.mobile;
});
```

Check the **Code Snippet** below for a practical example of the *ES5 approach* above:

```js
var users = [{mobile:'88005895##'},{mobile:'78408584##'},{mobile:'88008335##'}];
       
var mob = users.map( function(x) {
  return x.mobile;
});

console.log(mob);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can write it like this:

```js
var users = [ { mobile: '88005895##' },
  { mobile: '78408584##' },
  { mobile: '88008335##' } ];
  
  
users.map(userData => console.log(userData))
```

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript has a native `map` function for Array's, you can use it like so, in my example I've just written one function called `process` which just returns the `mobile` property on an object, I mean you could do all sorts if you wanted, again, this is just an example of what you **could** do.

I mean you could write it all on one line, i.e.

```
const demo = users.map(user => user.mobile);
```

```js
const users = [ 
  { mobile: '8800589595' },
  { mobile: '7840858487' },
  { mobile: '8800833524' } 
];

// Do some magic stuff here...
const process = u => u.mobile; 

// Map the array...
const demo = users.map(user => process(user));

// Results...
console.log(demo);
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
users = [ { mobile: '88005895##' },
  { mobile: '78408584##' },
  { mobile: '88008335##' } ];
var numbers = users.map(function(value, index, array){
 return value;
 
 });
var numbers2 = users.map(function(value, index, array){
 return value.mobile;
 });
var num='';
users.map(function(value, index, array){
 num+=value.mobile;
 return num;
 }); 
 console.log(numbers);
 console.log(numbers2);
 console.log(num);
```

Comment: not worked still returning same data. I just want array of numbers.

Comment: numbers2 returns number only.
what you exactly wants can you show your answer example

Comment: @SayedMohdAli i am sharing three scenario check if use full if you want separate umber add separator as desire

Comment: @AndrewL sir your answer is same like my second console, I assume here may user added # form his some resign , he not says to remove # for his entry.